# iOS - How to create views from Core Data entities

Tags: ios, core-data, uiview, key-value-observing

I have implemented Core Data in my app, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to create views from the model objects.

My Cat model object has these properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc;
```

I want to create a Cat view that displays the image as a UIImage, and displays the title and description as labels. Do I need to use a model proxy? I think KVO will be involved as well. Anyone know of a good tutorial for this? It seems like this would be a common task but the only tutorials I can find are about Core Data only and do not explain how to create view objects from the data.

Answer (score 3):

You associate your Cat `Model` object with your Cat `View` object using a `Controller` object.

You need to look up tutorials on MVC.

You probably have Binding's in mind. Where you bind any changes to the Model to the View. Cocoa has bindings, but only in Mac OS:

[Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html)

> Cocoa bindings are not supported in iOS. Instead, iOS uses a slightly modified version of the target-action model that adds flexibility in how you handle actions in your code.

That was from: [Porting from Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html)

Also take a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`. This might be of interest too.

You would have to create your own bindings class. We had one in an old iOS project I worked on.

The Binding class would use KVO and have a source key path, a destination key path, source object and destination object. On init you would setup your KVO observer on the source (your Model) and when it changes, you propagate that change to the destination (your View) using the destination key path. You would create the Biding in your controller object - as the View and Model shouldn't talk to each other directly (bad MVC)

Comment: Have you any code sample, demonstrating the setting-up of KVO in a controller object, to synchronize "source" and "destination" ? did your code also work bi-directional?  in MacOS Cocoa Bindings, editing some value in a Control, can immediately apply the new value into the model.  Sometimes directly, sometimes via some NSObjectController subclass (like the famous NSArrayController)